# Is there any algorithm that implements wavelet?

Tags: qiskit, hamiltonian-simulation

Is there any algorithm that implements wavelet (like there is Quantum Fourier Transform)? I've tried looking online, but couldn't find any, I wonder if something like this exists.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could you be looking for this: [Quantum Wavelet Transforms: Fast Algorithms and Complete Circuits](https://arxiv.org/abs/quant-ph/9809004)? (this links to arxiv.) In particular, this paper presents efficient circuits for the Haar and Daubechies wavelet transforms.